# Repeat the operation every 5 seconds for a specific number, and the entire array must be checked

Tags: javascript, algorithm, setinterval

I have to check all the values in this arrangement.
The entire data distribution variable is called 'subscribingUser', and I wonder if there is a problem or better way to create the following logic when you try to do something 10 every 5 seconds.

```
let loopCount = 10;
let NumberOfBundle = Math.ceil(subscribingUser.length / loopCount); // 176
let restOfBundle = subscribingUser.length % loopCount; // 8

let bundleCount = 1;
let start = 0;
let bundleInterval = setInterval(async() => {

   for(let i = start; i < loopCount; i++) {
       //Perform 10 specific actions ...
       await subscribingUser[i] ~
   };

   //Send all 10 and raise the BundleCount
   bundleCount += 1;
   start = loopCount;

   if (bundleCount == NumberOfBundle && restOfBundle != 0) {
       loopCount = restOfBundle - 1;
   } else {
       loopCount = loopCount * bundleCount;
   }

   if(bundleCount == NumberOfBundle + 1) {
       clearInterval(bundleInterval);
   }

}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, consider avoiding

```
for(...){
  await ...
}
```

since you will do your stuff sequentially which negates the interest of using bundles (to process each user in a bundle in parallel)

rather aim for

```
await Promise.all(users.map(u => doSomethingWithUser(u)))
```

2. Regarding the logic

You  may consider separating the bulking stuff from your "client" code

```js
function bulker(arr, n) {
  return {
    async forEach (fn, binding) {
      for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += n) {
        await fn.call(binding, arr.slice(i, i + n), i, i  +n >= arr.length)
      }
    }
  } 
}

const doSomethingWithUser = u => {
  console.log('go', u);
  return Promise.resolve(u)
}

;(async _=> {

  //choose whenever you want to wait or not
  //bulker just gives you the next slice once you "resolve"
  await bulker([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 2).forEach(async (users, i, done) => {
    await Promise.all(users.map(doSomethingWithUser))
    if (done) return
    return new Promise((ok, ko) => setTimeout(ok, 1000))
  })
  console.log('done!')
})()
```